# Wrong horizontal position for bootstrap data-toggle:tooltip when horizontal scroll appears

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, scrollbar

So im currently working in a project and it uses bootstrap tooltips like this :

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Exportar" class="pull-right">
```

This does the job, but if we shrink the browser until the horizontal scroll appears, the tooltip starts to move to the left like this:

[image: First its the correct position, the second shows where the tooltip moves to when shriking the browser as soon the scroll bar appears.]

Comment: Can you show me how you initialized tooltips in your javascript? I am having a lot of trouble replicating your issue. Typically I intialize mine like so $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container: 'body'});

Comment: $("body").tooltip({ selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]', animation : false });

Comment: there is a getCalculateOffset in the bootstrap.js. Might have something to do with it?

Comment: Seems that comment the line :    $tip.offset(offset); in the applyPlacement method solves the issue.

Comment: Does it cause any other unexpected issues?

Comment: As soon as it reaches the line:  $tip.addClass('in'); in the same method, the tooltip is correctly rendered, so im not really understanding why this method is structured this way.

Comment: The code that appears after seems to have relation to the arrow position but it still appears correctly before that it seems. I will still analyse further this aspect.